# error "No enough storage is available to process this command" window server 2008

Tags: active-directory, window

I created a web service in c# that read all the groups and users name from the active directory, this function was working fine without any errors but now I am getting an error

```
"Not enough storage is available to process this command"
```

and this function is connecting to window server 2008

```
<!--Used for Active Directory connections-->
<add name="LDAPConStr" connectionString="LDAP://dc=servername,dc=cc,dc=hh"/>

DirectoryEntry ldapServer = new DirectoryEntry(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LDAPConStr"].ConnectionString);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldapServer);
```

I checked the servers and the memory is fine with it, 
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution 
[Description of the IRPStackSize parameter in Windows 2000, in Windows XP, and in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;285089&x=15&y=11)